# How a multimeter can't measure currents in parallels?

Tags: resistors, current-measurement, parallel, multimeter, current-source

Today, I put two resistors in parallels ( R1 = 1k Ohms and R2 = 10k Ohms). The voltage in is 13.63 V ( It's DC voltage). When I use a DMM to measure currents flow through R1 and R2, the result of each current is equal. I think it can't be like that but I can't explain. How can I overcome the result? Many thanks.

Comment: Draw a schematic of what you measured, including the multimeter in the schematic. Realize that the current the meter reads is the current flowing through the meter.

Comment: Please give more description or a schematic/drawing to show your circuit and testing method. To expand on what The Photon said, the meter has to be wired in series with the current you're testing. That means breaking the circuit and inserting the meter as a series resistor (for standard probe testing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes that beginners often make with current measurement that they don't make with a voltage measurement.

1) To measure current, you have to break the circuit and measure the current flowing through the component, by putting the meter in series with it. Many put the meter onto a current range, and then measure across the component. This simply makes a very wrong voltage measurement.

In the case of two components in parallel, it amounts to making physically the same measurement in both cases. Which could fit with your results.

2) On the voltage range, a typical DMM is more or less perfect. It draws so little current that it rarely disturbs the circuit being probed. On a current range, a typical DMM is far from perfect. Most require a voltage drop across them that is usually significant compared to the voltages in a typical circuit. This often 200mV, it could be more.

When measuring two components in parallel (and of course breaking the circuit to measure them individually), the extra drop caused by the meter will upset the circuit conditions somewhat, and the two measured currents are unlikely to add up to the total measured current.